# Getting PHP errors only on my machine (I think)

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome

I am running OSX 10.9.2 and using Chrome 39.0.2171.95.

I am working on a custom WordPress theme and am getting this strange error only in chrome. FF and Safari are okay. Here is the weird thing... I open the site in Browserstack using the same setup I have, the error doesn't show.

I have tried to re-install chrome but no luck. Could this be a computer issue or is there something wrong with the code?

Errors:
Warning: Unknown: open(/tmp/sess_50c0d117406337c84b96e53630720674, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct ("your home directory path"/cgi-bin/tmp) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Have you read the error messages? They tell you exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The warning looks like chrome by default is blocking caching. I don't know why that would mess up your results unless it is a requirement in your code to pull session data info to run the rest of the code on pages. Try enabling cookies? Thats the first thing I would do with that message to start from?